# Reduce the space between two lines in a latex table

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I am writing a table in latex in which one entry (an algorithm name) is too large. I divided its content in three lines as it is shown in the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Problem} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Mean objective value}} \\
    \midrule
    & Algorithm X & \scriptsize  Algorithm X without &  Algorithm X with \\
    &             & \scriptsize component A and with &  component C \\
    &             & \scriptsize and component B      & \\
    \midrule
    eil51         & \textbf{427.267} & \underline{1286.37} & 439.467 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

However, those lines are too separated when compiling to pdf.

[image]

Is it possible to reduce the space between two table lines? Is there any  other solution?

Possible solutions:

- I have tried `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` and it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post working examples, not just fragments. `\\[-0.3ex]` for example will reduce the space, but only if really needed. Since you're using `booktabs`: `\addlinespace[-0.3ex]`

Comment: Thank you very much! The command `\addlinespace[-1.5ex]` worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok, and that's why you accepted the other answer which does not use `\addlinespace`? :D

Comment: I would accept both, but I used his command in other tables too! ^^

Comment: Alright, noticed for future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd add the clauses below the main entry in the header:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\descrcell}[2]{%
  \scriptsize
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\normalsize#1\\#2\end{tabular}%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Problem} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Mean objective value}} \\
\midrule
& Algorithm X
& \descrcell{Algorithm X}{without component A \\ and with component B}
& \descrcell{Algorithm X}{with component C} \\
\midrule
eil51         & \textbf{427.267} & \underline{1286.37} & 439.467 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever and elegant solution. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can we apply this solution for the title section for the `Mean objective value`? When I wrap it inside `\descrcell{}` it adds additonal space

Comment: @alper Very cryptic. *What* do you want to do with the header?

Comment: Example one column of my header:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqQAr.png ; I just wanted to remove spacing in it. But since the journal template provides this, its better I don't change its format.

Comment: @alper You're looking at the wrong tool. Please ask a question with the details.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to reduce or enlarge the linespacing with `\addlinespace` if the `booktabs` package is used:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
Without \verb!\addlinespace!

\begin{tabular}{lccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Problem} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Mean objective value}} \\
    \midrule
    & Algorithm X & \scriptsize  Algorithm X without &  Algorithm X with \\
    &             & \scriptsize component A and with &  component C \\
    &             & \scriptsize and component B      & \\
    \midrule
    eil51         & \textbf{427.267} & \underline{1286.37} & 439.467 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

With \verb!\addlinespace!

\begin{tabular}{l*{3}c}    
    \toprule
    \textbf{Problem} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Mean objective value}} \\
    \midrule
    & Algorithm X & \scriptsize  Algorithm X without &  Algorithm X with \\
    \addlinespace[-0.3ex]
    &             & \scriptsize component A and with &  component C \\
    \addlinespace[-0.4ex]
    &             & \scriptsize and component B      & \\
    \midrule
    eil51         & \textbf{427.267} & \underline{1286.37} & 439.467 \\
    \bottomrule


\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]